# "No matter what" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

How does one say "no matter what" in Spanish? In English it would be akin to saying "at any cost" or "come what may". I saw **pase lo que pase** somewhere. Is it accurate? Or is there a better way to say it in regular conversations without sounding bookish? If there are regional variations, I would love to know what the Mexicans use.

I am trying to translate the following sentence:

> No matter what, don't miss the meeting.

Is the following correct?

> Pase lo que pase, no vayas a faltar a la junta.

Comment: `pase lo que pase` sounds about right.

Comment: I would translate the sentence as: `Pase lo que pase, no faltes a la junta.`

Comment: no importa lo que pase, no faltes a la reunión/no te pierdas las reunión

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in Chile, *no matter what* means *pase lo que pase*, o *suceda lo que suceda* (this one less common). I don't know what do Mexicans prefer.

@itziki is right, but both options are OK:

> Pase lo que pase, no vayas a faltar a la junta.

and

> Pase lo que pase, no faltes a la junta.

The second one sounds prettier, though ^_^

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to know a little bit more about the English phrase you want to translate.  "Pase lo que pase" translates to "no matter what (and an implied **happens**)".  But the translation is dependent on the verb and the interrogative word (5 W's & H).

No matter **who says it** = Lo diga quien lo diga...

No matter **what you believe** = Creas lo que creas...

No matter **where they go** = Vayan donde vayan...

No matter **when he goes** = Vaya cuando vaya...

No matter **why he runs** = Corra por lo que corra...

No matter **how she washes herself** = Se lavara como se lavara...

Where(donde), when(cuando) and how(como) in Spanish generally translate "no matter **interrogative + verb**" to "**conditional verb + interrogative + conditional verb**".

Who (quien), what(que) and why(por que) being exceptions that throw a "lo" in the mix with a rule that I don't really understand (read: just because).

I learned Castillian Spanish (Spain) but I'd be willing to bet this goes all the way across the board.

Answer (score 2):

I lived in Paraguay for a couple years, and down there the common phase for "No matter what" was: "Sí o sí" (meaning directly, "Yes or yes"). This was used in sentences to demonstrate the imperativeness of an action.

For example: "You need to go to the the meeting, no matter what." --> "Necesitas asistir a la reunión, sí o sí."

Comment: This is also used in Spain.